# Ordering of bars in grouped barplots using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to reorder the Number of Beetles, from 0 to above 15? I have tried converting the "Number of Beetle" to a factor but it did not work.

[image: The plot obtained by using the code is also provided]

```r
data<-g
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'g' not found


#############################################original basic code
ggplot(data,aes(x=Locality.Division))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Number.of.Beetle,),position="dodge")+
  facet_wrap(~Building.Age)
#> Error in ggplot(data, aes(x = Locality.Division)): could not find function "ggplot"

############################################wanted to change the order of building age, so convert it to a factor
data.new<-g
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'g' not found
g$Building.Age<-factor(g$Building.Age,
                              levels = c("Under 5 Years","5-10 Years","Above 10 Years"))
#> Error in factor(g$Building.Age, levels = c("Under 5 Years", "5-10 Years", : object 'g' not found


########################################## run same code by modifying the new name of the data
ggplot(g,aes(x=Locality.Division))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Number.of.Beetle,),position="dodge")+
  facet_wrap(~Building.Age)
#> Error in ggplot(g, aes(x = Locality.Division)): could not find function "ggplot"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`.

Comment: https://github.com/Sajidha-Mohammed/Beetle-Data/blob/708bf55455c431a1ebf51262899cf74c377dc459/data.csv

Comment: This is a link to the data sample. Please do check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to order the unique values of column `Number.of.Beetle` and coerce to a factor variable.

```
data$Number.of.Beetle <- trimws(data$Number.of.Beetle)
lvls <- unique(data$Number.of.Beetle)
lvls <- stringr::str_sort(lvls, numeric = TRUE)
data$Number.of.Beetle <- factor(data$Number.of.Beetle, levels = lvls)

lvls2 <- unique(data$Building.Age)
lvls2 <- lvls2[c(2, 3, 1)]
data$Building.Age <- factor(data$Building.Age, levels = lvls2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Locality.Division))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Number.of.Beetle), position = "dodge")+
  facet_wrap(~ Building.Age)
```

---

### Data

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sajidha-Mohammed/Beetle-Data/708bf55455c431a1ebf51262899cf74c377dc459/data.csv"
data <- read.csv(url)
```